# Increase curl timeout for busy servers

Tags: php, curl

I've increased the timeout but it doesn't work.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost.com/test.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 999);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($response);
```

Comment: Is it the connection timeout? OR is `test.php` execution is taking long and is timing out???

Comment: @MilanChheda It timeouts without even connecting.

Comment: @AdamWright Then it is connecttimeout. Try my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT option to it.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 600); //10 minutes
```